# Thresholding an image gives fuzzy black output

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, image-thresholding

Im preprocessing a qrcode to read it. I threshold the image, but sometimes I get a fuzzy black output, sometimes i get the proper binary image. Why is this happening? IM using C# and Emgucv.

Here is my code:

```
                    Image<Gray, byte> grayimg = inoutImg.Convert<Gray, byte>();  
                    grayimg = grayimg.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(this.tbbcrthreshold.Value), new Gray(255));
                    bcrthreshimgbox.Image = grayimg.Bitmap;
```

This is the Image im trying to threshold:
[image]

And this is the Image I get sometimes after i crop the image using roi :

[image]

Because of this, im unable to read the code.

Comment: How does your image look before thresholding? Are you displaying the image in a one to one scale, or is the image re-scaled?

Comment: Im cropping the image before thresholding.

Comment: Do we have to guess the original image type and content ? I am doing a computation and the answer is 553. What is going wrong ?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Bro, I have mentioned in the question that its a QR code image. 27.65/20 is 553. Atleast I tried to find your computational error!

Comment: I have updated the question with the QR code i was trying to threshold.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not mention that I was doing a computation the number 217.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the qr code image you shared and works with every threshold value <200 (as it's the background value).

Here's an example with 100 as threashold.

```
 Image<Gray,byte> qr = new Image<Gray, byte>("qr.png");
 CvInvoke.Threshold(qr, qr, 100, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
 CvInvoke.Imshow("qr",qr);
```

Output:

[image: Qr code binary]